# Bootstrap tabs lazy loading data does not work with dialogs service

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an application which requires a tabbed pane and dialogs. 
I am injecting 'ui.bootstrap' and 'dialogs' services for generating the dialog. However when I include these services the tabs doesnt seem to get displayed.
in case I remove these services while loading my module, the tabs work fine.
Here is the http://plnkr.co/edit/NddkHpIlxoeptgoe3zXk?p=preview plunker link for the same.

`HTML`

**script.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs']);
```

If I load `myApp` without using ui.bootstrap and sialogs service, the tabs seem to be displayed correctly. However I need to use dialogs in my code and hence need to load the services.

The complete example is available on `plunker`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend using a release version of my dialogs service (https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service/releases) as well rather than the github pages version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had multiple `tabset` and `tab` directives, and the one you had in scripts file caused error

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/evCzuOYsT3uqZd6PBgRI?p=preview)

Comment: I have written a custom tabset directive which will load the tabs only after clicking on the tabs (lazy loading). Is there any way to have the custom tabs and also include the ui.bootstrap?